L2 blockchain on solana
I wanted to create an L2 solution for community platform using Solana. Can anyone tell me how should,I begin and suggest any resources for this if possible.

I would first recommend reading this excellent piece on why Solana Need L2s and Appchains
You would get a lot clear idea on usecases and some technical insights.
Next, go through Sovereign's Rollup basics. Sovereign's SDK is under active development but if you are really serious, you can reach out to their team and get early access.
Go through Sovereign SDK's README file and you'd get a much better as well: https://github.com/Sovereign-Labs/sovereign-sdk
It'd be quite difficult to build it entirely yourself without enough knowledge on core concepts like consensus, slots, blocks, sequencers, verification, zk etc. So I would recommend get those basics cleared first, there are a lot of resources for them online as these concepts are not Solana specific.
